# Redirect all traffic from VirtualBox in a Tor

Tags: ubuntu

Host UBUNTU 14.04 i need redirect all traffic from VirtualBox Windows guest OS in a network of TOR? How to do it correctly to prevent leaks?

Answer (score 2):

You can 'torify' your ubuntu machine, and route all traffic through tor, 
see the wiki here for guides for that:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy

Or you can set up a 'Whonix' gateway, and put your windows virtual machine behind that.
There is a guide for that here:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems#Windows-Whonix-Workstation